# -webkit- vs -moz-transition

Tags: css, webkit, mozilla, css-transitions

I am using CSS3 transitions on my site and the -webkit- seems to be working, whilst the -moz- is not.

Here is the CSS:

```
article {z-index: 2; float: left; overflow: hidden; position: relative; -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s ease-in-out; }

.mousedown{-webkit-transform: translate(-180px, 0) !important; -moz-transform: translate(-180px, 0) !important; }
```

Just using jQuery to add the mousedown class onto the article.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Could someone explain why this was downvoted? Looks okay to me.

Comment: @Justin E. Morgan It did go out of date, I updated it after the down vote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firefox 4 and above supports `-moz-transition`. See the [documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transition).

Comment: Updated the answer to this, old was incorrect, now it IS supported.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: see comments. Support for -moz-transition has now been added. Yay!

There is no such thing as -moz-transition (yet), sorry. Mozilla will do transforms, but webkit is still the only engine rendering transitions.

Comment: Well that answers my question, and confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, transitions aren't supported on CSS transforms in Mozilla.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions

Answer (score 2):

Support for -moz-transition has been added in Gecko 1.9.3 (Firefox 3.7), so right now -moz-transition will only work in a Firefox 3.7 alpha release or Minefield (Firefox nightly build).

Answer (score 1):

opera is supporting it since 10.5, and much better than webkit

Answer (score -1):

CSS transitions, provide a way to control animation speed when changing CSS properties. Instead of having property changes take effect immediately, you can cause the changes in a property to take place over a period of time. For example, if you change the color of an element from white to black, usually the change is instantaneous. With CSS transitions enabled, changes occur at time intervals that follow an acceleration curve, all of which can be customized.

Comment: Arun, the question seems to ask why -webkit works and -moz doesn't - can you throw any light on that?

Comment: moz is firefox format or syntax ,whereas webkit is of chrome and safari based whenever moz transitions are applied in css,it mostly affects the specific browser(ie firefox),if it is not working,then browser needs to be updated for transitions to take place.